# Regular expression with comma and numbers

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

I want a Regular expression for a string which can have 4 to 6 digits number and a comma to separate them which is already done by this regular expression:

```
@"^(\d{1,6},{1})+$"
```

What i don't want is comma at the end

This existing regular expression works for string of type:0234,23544,234332,

I want a regular expression for following string:0234,23544,234332.

Comment: You appear to have a full stop at the end?

Comment: Surely you want `{4,6}` not `{1,6}`?

Comment: Could you show valid and invalid strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `^\d{1,6}(,\d{1,6})*$` should do the job. If you want 4-6 digits in a group, replace `{1,6}` with `{4,6}`.

Comment: This is the correct regex, assuming that the period at the end of the string shouldn't be there.

Comment: You could add an optionnal dot at the end of the regex `\.?$`

Answer (score 2):

I am still unclear about the (.) at the end or not

but `/^\d{1,6},+\d+$/` will match any string as asked not ending with `, or .`

[Demo and Regex Explained](http://regex101.com/r/gK4rC7)

Comment: Oh dear, you pattern matches `0234{,,,{},23544` as well. Learn about `[]` operator, please.

Comment: That's better now, not perfect though :)

Comment: @RomanZavalov will this do, and thanks this [] is learned forever.

Answer (score 1):

try this regular expression

```
^\d{1,6}(,\d{1,6})*(\.)?$
```

Comment: It will match a comma at the end of string.

Comment: But he said: "What i don't want is comma at the end"

Answer (score 1):

i would advice

```
(\d{4,6}[,|\.])
```

if you match 'global' e.g. all occurrences you will get this:

```
0234,
23544,
234332.
0234,
23544,
234332,
```

take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)!

for perl it would be

```
m/(\d{4,6}[,|\.])/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probably:

```
/^(\d{4,6},?\b)+$/
```